# Number of matchsticks of dimensions $1 \times 1$ that can fit in a rectangular grid

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

An $a \times b$ rectangluar grid comprises $ab$ square cells of size $1 \times 1$.  Every square cell’s perimeter is made of one matchstick per side, where adjacent square cells share the match on their common edge.

How many distinct such grids are possible if 178 match sticks are used? (Note: An $a\times b$ grid is the same as a $b\times a$ grid.)

---

My attempt :-

I tried to come up with the general expression by taking some cases like $1\times 1$ (4 matchsticks) , $2\times 1$ (7 matchsticks) and so on, but I am not able to find any pattern.

The official solution just gives a general formula i.e. $(a+1)(b)+a(b+1)$.  How can we get it with the help from combinatorics.  I am not able to understand how it was derived, and what if instead of $1 \times 1$ matchsticks there would have been matchsticks of say $2 \times 2$ dimensions?

Answer (score 4):

Trying small examples is a great way to establish a pattern. But it is also necessary to think.

Every vertical line contains $a$ matchsticks. Every horizontal line contains $b$ matchsticks. There are $b+1$ vertical lines and $a+1$ horizontal lines, so the number of matchsticks in an $(a\times b)$-grid is
$$a(b+1)+b(a+1).$$
To find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that an $(a\times b)$-grid contains exactly $178$ matchsticks, you want to find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$a(b+1)+b(a+1)=178.$$
You can search by brute force, knowing that $2ab<178$. But it helps to notice that
$$2\times\big(a(b+1)+b(a+1)\big)+1=4ab+2a+2b+1=(2a+1)(2b+1),$$
so you want to factor $2\times178+1=357$.